# Why laravel ApiResource Route PUT method doesn't work?

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel

I'm trying to update category lists. But its not working on put method. After changing to POST method its working. Can't i use laravel ApiResource Routes?

```js
 Route::get('category',[CategoryController::class, 'index']);
        Route::post('category',[CategoryController::class, 'store']);
        Route::delete('category/{id}',[CategoryController::class, 'delete']);
        Route::get('category/{id}',[CategoryController::class, 'show']);
        Route::post('category/{id}',[CategoryController::class, 'update']);

//        Route::apiResource('category', CategoryController::class)
//            ->except('edit','create');
```

```js
const updateCategory = async (data,e) => {

        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("name",data.name);
        formData.append("img_path",data.img_path[0]);
        formData.append("body",data.body);

        const response = await axios.post(`/api/admin/category/${id}`, formData)
        console.log(response)
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

[image]

Comment: Try moving it up the chain of the resources, and also what is the error exactly? is it not showing anything or is it returning a 404?

Comment: Data not sending correctly in PUT method

Comment: From Laravel Docs: `Note: Since HTML forms only support POST and GET, PUT and DELETE methods will be spoofed by automatically adding a _method hidden field to your form.` Also, have you tried `axios.put` instead of post?

Comment: They get, delete and put are all pointing towards the same route, so maybe try using `any` > https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#:~:text=When%20defining%20multiple,the%20correct%20route.

Comment: The solution is in @harish durga's comment. You cannot upload a file in method put. You have to be post and add `_method` hidden field to your form.

Comment: try adding formData.append("_method", "PUT")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
   const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("name",data.name);
        formData.append("img_path",data.img_path[0]);
        formData.append("body",data.body);
        formData.append("_method","put")

        const response = await axios.post(`/api/admin/category/${id}`, formData)
        console.log(response)
```